# Downloading Excel File via webmethod response by ajax calling

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, excel

I have created a webmethod and  the method just send a Excel file as webresponse.When i run only the webmethod it works fine as want
[image]

My webmethod is following:

```
 public void Export_ex(string elem)
    {

            string elements = elem;
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "data:application/vnd.ms-excel";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Print.xls");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<html xmlns:x=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel\">");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<head>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<div>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<META http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-     8\">");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<x:ExcelWorkbook>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<x:ExcelWorksheets>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<x:ExcelWorksheet>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<x:Name>Report Data</x:Name>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<x:WorksheetOptions>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<x:ValidPrinterInfo/>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</x:Print>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</x:WorksheetOptions>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</x:ExcelWorksheet>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</x:ExcelWorksheets>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</x:ExcelWorkbook>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</xml>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<![endif]--> ");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</head>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(elements);

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
           // HttpContext.Current.Response.End();


        }
```

but when i call it from javascript function by ajax calling nothing happened. My ajax method is following :

```
 var str = "something"
             var data = { elem: str };
             $.ajax({
                 type: 'POST',
                 url: "ImageSaving.asmx/Export_ex",
                 data: JSON.stringify(data),
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 mimeType: 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
                 success: function (response) {
                     var show = response.d;

                  },
                 failure: function (msg) {
                     alert("Error occur, could not load the service.");
                 }
             });
```

I could not understand where i am getting wrong?? Any suggestion regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, you cannot download file from client side. I advice to use a hidden button server side and simulate the click from another button client side.

Regards.